# Cast an object dynamically back to what it was

Tags: c#, reflection, types, casting

I want to add Items to a Dockpanel. I receive the Items (e.g. an Image, Button, etc.) as an Object.

How can I cast the object back to what it was and add to the Dockpanel?

I tried something like this

```
Dockpanel.Children.Add((T)Convert.ChangeType(object, typeof(T)));
```

Comment: That's not casting - that's converting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

The problem with your code is that you can't simply add `object`s to `DockPanel.Children` because it is a [`UIElementCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection?view=netframework-4.7.1) meaning that **you can only add [`UIElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement?view=netframework-4.7.1)s** to it.

---

## Solution

Therefore, instead of

```
Dockpanel.Children.Add((T) Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T)));
```

(which doesn't compile) you need to **cast the object you want to add to an `UIElement`** like this:

```
DockPanel.Children.Add((UIElement) obj);
```

---

What you need to take care of is that `obj` is in fact a `UIElement` such as `Button`, `Image`, `TextBox` etc. or the cast to `UIElement` will fail.

---

## Recommendation

Use a helper method or an an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) like this

```
public static void AddChild(this DockPanel dockPanel, T childToAdd) where T : UIElement
{
    dockPanel.Children.Add(childToAdd);
}
```

which has the advantage of being **easy to use** and **only allowing valid inputs** thanks to the generic constraint `where T : UIElement` which means *"where the object to add must derive from `UIElement`"*.

You can then call the method like this:

```
this.MyDockPanel.AddChild(new Image());
this.MyDockPanel.AddChild(new Button());
```

---

## EDIT - Real Requirements

The OP has clarified their actual requirements, namely

> I get an Image in an object Array - I want to Cast it back to an Image - Then I want to add it to the Dockpanel - The same code should work with Buttons too

which means that we want to add all items contained in

```
object[] myItems = ...
```

to our `DockPanel` named `myDockPanel`.

Let's make use of our extension method from above and we can now do this:

```
object[] myItems = ...;

foreach(object obj in myItems)
{
    this.myDockPanel.AddChild(obj as UIElement);
}
```

and voila, we're done - no need to cast back to an `Image`, we simply cast to `UIElement` for reasons explained above and the code works for `Button`s etc. as well.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand, where the object with the image inside is left. Shouldn't the call then be like: 
this.MyDockPanel.AddChild(object);

Comment: @Joe I can't really follow you... first of all, you cannot name something `object` because that is already a type name in C#. If you mean something like e.g. a `Grid` that contains an `Image` and you want to add that grid to the `DockPanel`, simply use `this.MyDockPanel.AddChild(myGrid)`.

Comment: Ok, this is the procedure:
- I get an Image in an object Array
- I want to Cast it back to an Image
- Then I want to add it to the Dockpanel
- The same code should work with Buttons too

Comment: @Joe please see the edited answer - I came up with a copy&ready code.

Comment: @Joe great to hear that it worked. Thank you very much for making this the accepted answer :)